# How to access website served by vagrant (ubuntu) VM through a second (Windows) VM?

Tags: windows, ubuntu, networking, vagrant, virtualbox

I am currently working on a website on a Vagrant (ubuntu) VM which I am then able to develop locally and test on my development computer (mac OS). For testing in IE11 and Edge I need to access this site via a second VM which is running Windows in Virtualbox.

Bridged or internal network settings in VirtualBox are not working; they can be set up for the Windows VM but are overwritten by the Vagrant VM on launch and have no effect if they are set up while the Vagrant VM is running. I have also tried adding public and private network configurations to the Vagrant file as per the documentation in order to make an IP address available to other machines. In every case, the IP of the ubuntu machine is not accessible from the Windows machine, both in the browser and via pinging in the command line.

I don't expect there is any code I can provide to clarify this problem but I'll post anything else that might be helpful to reproduce this issue. The main thing is to set up a website on a Vagrant VM and try, using any of the standard Vagrant or Virtual Box network settings, to access this website in a browser in a Windows VM.

Answer (score 0):

You need to link the 2 VMs with private network.

This is done in the Vagrant file on provision:

> config.vm.network "private_network"

Checkout (https://github.com/najeeb-rifaat/vagrant-swarm-cluster?files=1) for example.